# Problem ckeditor4,5 with vue 3 about How to get text backward from last cursor?

Tags: vuejs3, ckeditor5, ckeditor4

Start at cursor point backward util find character ">"
For Example

input:

`<p>Text <strong>Example Test</strong></p>`

LastPosition() => [0,17]
Output: Example Test

input:

`<p>Text <strong>Example Test</strong></p><figure class="table"><table><tbody><tr><td>Text1</td><td>Text2</td><td>Text3</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></figure>`

LastPosition() => [1, 0, 2, 0, 5]
Output: Text3

Start at cursor point backward util find character ">" ?